# How can I configure Windows Server 2003 to route to each other using VPN?

Tags: windows-server-2003, vpn, rras

I'm using two Windows Server 2003 machines.

Our professor asked us to have the two routers communicate with one another via VPN.

Here's a diagram of the setup:

[image]

Is there a tutorial online you would recommend to accomplish this, or maybe you can help me out in this medium?

Thank you. :)

Comment: Is this your homework assignment to figure out how to do it, or is this necessary to do the assignment? :)

Comment: It's a homework assignment. I'm kind of lost in this subject. He wants those two Server 2003 machines to act as routers using VPN. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

search the Windows Server 2003 feature RRAS or "Routing and Remote Access" Service which does VPN for server-to-server.